# Specified platform toolset (v120) is not installed VS 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Recently installed VS 2013 in my machine. earlier I was using VS2010.

When I open the VS2010 project in VS2013 it asked me for upgrade, I gave option YES.
No I am getting this error message when I build my solution.

Please help!!

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: error MSB8020: The build tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found

Comment: I can see some list of files under "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120" .. So v120 is installed in my machine?

Comment: could you please create a new C++ project in VS 2013 and check if it builds correctly with v120? if yes, then it is a problem with upgrade, if no with VS installation

Comment: I have verified it already and new project is builds correctly without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

`v120` is the build toolset for Visual C++ 2013 using the Windows 8.1 SDK.

So the real question is what Edition of **Visual Studio** did you install? If the `v120` toolset is missing, then you may have installed a version of Visual Studio 2013 without C++ tools, or perhaps have a corrupted installation.

Note: `v110` is VS 2012 with the Windows 8.0 SDK, `v100` was VS 2010 with the Windows 7 SDK, and `v140` is VS 2015. `v130` was skipped.

Comment: I have installed VS2013. I can see v120 folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\

Comment: Which edition of VS 2013? Express for Windows, Express for Web, Express for Windows Desktop, Community, Pro, Test Pro, Enterprise? Also what OS are you using?

Comment: Ok, that's really odd. Go to Control Panel - > Programs and Features -> select VS 2013 and hit "Change". Then use Repair.